# Why do Rails session cookies start with an underscore?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

By default, Rails session cookies have names that start with an underscore: `_app_session`.

What's the reason for this?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271839/why-do-many-sites-name-cookies-with-a-leading-underscore